# Save elements of Numpy array into different numpy arrays dependent on specific area of start array (Python)

Tags: python, numpy, loops, area

I want to save elements of one numpy array into diffrent numpy arrays dependent on areas i define from the first array

```
length_of_start_array = 42 // this number can change i loop over diffrent arrays 
start_indices_of_areas = [2, 5, 6]
length_of_areas = [2, 3, 1, 36]
```

So what i want to do is that i loop over this array with e.g. 42 elements and that it saves the elements in the first array with its elements from (0-2) then i want a second array which saves its elements from (3-5) then from (5-6) and then form (6-42)
So my understanding is, that i need two loops?
one that specifies which area i want to loop over and a second one that loops over it the amount of length that area has. I have tried that but failed

```
for area in range(0, len(length_of_areas)):
        for element in range(0, length_of_areas[area]):
            //further code
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a partial solution - and there will be other, more elegant solutions possible (e.g. using list comprehensions)

You don't need the array lengths when you have the indices.
I print the lists instead of making list of lists, so you should change
this.

```
import random

length_of_start_array = 20 # this number can change i loop over diffrent arrays 

randomlist = random.sample(range(1, 100), length_of_start_array)
start_indices_of_areas = [0, 2, 5, 6]
#length_of_areas = [2, 3, 1, 36]

print(randomlist)

for i, index in enumerate(start_indices_of_areas):
   if i==len(start_indices_of_areas)-1:
      splitArray=randomlist[index:]
   else: 
      length=start_indices_of_areas[i+1]-start_indices_of_areas[i]
      splitArray=randomlist[index:index+length]
   print(splitArray)
```